# Use variable in Javascript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

i use angular 6 and rxjs.

i define data1 as a list of array.

```
let interestingFields = [ 'traitement','datedebut', 'datefin'];
this.ppssToDisplay.subscribe(ppsList => { 
  this.data1 = [
    interestingFields,
    ...ppsList.map(pps => interestingFields.map(field => pps[field]))
    ];
    console.log(this.data1);
});
```

But i must use data1 out the fonction;`

i try `this.data2 = this.data1;` But it doesn't work

```
console.log(this.data1); pps.component.ts:71 (4) [Array(3), Array(3), Array(3), Array(3)]
console.log(this.data2); undefined
```

How i can do ?

Comment: `this.data1 = data1` ?

Comment: *"i try this.data1 = `const data1`; But it doesn't work"* -- read about the [`const`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) JavaScript keyword. And remove the TypeScript tag from the question. There is no TypeScript into it. As it is now it is pure JavaScript.

Comment: @jonas I edit the question in order to you understand. thanks you

Comment: Are you performing your console.log(this.data2) inside the subscribe block, or outside of it?

Comment: outside, i want simply?? use this.data1 outside subscribe block...

Comment: @Jonas i don't understand the solve, can youhelp me ?